# jQuery slide toggle checkbox cant change background colour

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, slidetoggle

I am trying to change the background colour of the toggle to green when it is turned on. I think I have done everything correctly, but the background just stays grey.

What am I doing wrong?

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackbarham/84Qkz/)

```
$('.slider-button').toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on').parent().next('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('.slider-frame').addClass('green');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').parent().next('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $('.slider-frame').removeClass('green');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your style `background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #e2e2e2 0%, #e2e2e2 0.27%, #d8d8d8 100%);` is overriding the background color

Comment: one suggestion..try changing the outer circle's colour.look's elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Add the style

```
#stage .slider-frame.green {
    background-color: #5fca42 !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.32), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.32), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.32), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #5fca42 0%, #5fca42 0.27%, #d8d8d8 100%);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YFc28/)

Comment: This doesn't explain why you need to change it. OP asked what he was doing wrong... not just how to fix it :)

Comment: @Doug I'd added a comment to the question

Answer (score 1):

If you change the following, its working:

```
#stage .slider-frame.green {
    background: #5fca42 !important;
}
```

So basically just `background:` instead of `background-color:`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/84Qkz/2/

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this to your css. This will prevent the override you are currently getting

```
#stage .slider-frame.green {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS will solve your problem

```
#stage .slider-frame.green {
    background-color: #5fca42 !important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #5fca42 0%, #5fca42 0.27%, #d8d8d8 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #5fca42 0%, #5fca42 0.27%, #d8d8d8 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #5fca42 0%, #5fca42 0.27%, #d8d8d8 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #5fca42 0%, #5fca42 0.27%, #d8d8d8 100%);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.32), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.32), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.32), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
z-index:9999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are defining the colour of `.slider-button` as white.
2. `.slider-button` is nested inside `.slider-frame`.
3. `slider-frame` is given the additional CSS rule that makes it green
4. The green isn't showing because the background colour of the element within it is still white.

Solution...

Change

```
#stage .slider-frame.green {....}
```

to...

```
#stage .slider-frame.green .slider-button {....}
```

So you are now changing the colour of `.slider-button`, not `.slider-frame`

[Fiddle me this.](http://jsfiddle.net/BLbRk/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was actually the background (or the slider area) that I wanted to change not the button colour itself. I have updated my fiddle with the correct code now. Thanks again.